# Pygame running main

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

So I started fiddling with pygame, having never used python before.

My problem is that the screen won't draw, I had been following a tutorial and this is what the code looks like

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals.import *

def run_game():
    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
    game_clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    game_loop = true
    while game_loop:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                game_loop = false

        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()
```

So what this is supposed to do is just produce a black screen, however if I run it from within IDLE (F5) I get the following output:

```
 Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC
 v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 Type "copyright", "credits" or
 "license()" for more information.
 >>> 
 =========== RESTART: C:\Users\Cornelius\Desktop\Pycman\lib\main.py ===========
 >>>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that python uses `True` and `False` not `true` and `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget an important line:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    run_game()
```

you need to run the function,

that is all..

Comment: Thanks :) that did it.